# Qt with Dlib and CUDA

Tags: c++, qt, dlib

I'm trying to run Qt with Dlib. What happens is that every algorithm from Dlib that requires CUDA crashes without errors and if i run the same code on visual studio it works perfectly. Qt and Dlib was built with Visual Studio 2015 x64 and CUDA version is 8.0.

The code is some example from Dlib that can use CUDA for better performance:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <dlib/dnn.h>
    #include <dlib/data_io.h>
    #include <dlib/image_processing.h>
    #include <dlib/gui_widgets.h>


    using namespace std;
    using namespace dlib;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    template <long num_filters, typename SUBNET> using con5d = con<num_filters,5,5,2,2,SUBNET>;
    template <long num_filters, typename SUBNET> using con5  = con<num_filters,5,5,1,1,SUBNET>;

    template <typename SUBNET> using downsampler  = relu<affine<con5d<32, relu<affine<con5d<32, relu<affine<con5d<16,SUBNET>>>>>>>>>;
    template <typename SUBNET> using rcon5  = relu<affine<con5<45,SUBNET>>>;

    using net_type = loss_mmod<con<1,9,9,1,1,rcon5<rcon5<rcon5<downsampler<input_rgb_image_pyramid<pyramid_down<6>>>>>>>>;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


int main(int argc, char** argv) try
{
    if (argc == 1)
    {
        cout << "Call this program like this:" << endl;
        cout << "./dnn_mmod_face_detection_ex mmod_human_face_detector.dat faces/*.jpg" << endl;
        cout << "\nYou can get the mmod_human_face_detector.dat file from:\n";
        cout << "http://dlib.net/files/mmod_human_face_detector.dat.bz2" << endl;
        return 0;
    }


    net_type net;
    deserialize(argv[1]) >> net;  

    image_window win;
    for (int i = 2; i < argc; ++i)
    {
        matrix<rgb_pixel> img;
        load_image(img, argv[i]);

        // Upsampling the image will allow us to detect smaller faces but will cause the
        // program to use more RAM and run longer.
        while(img.size() < 1800*1800)
            pyramid_up(img);

        // Note that you can process a bunch of images in a std::vector at once and it runs
        // much faster, since this will form mini-batches of images and therefore get
        // better parallelism out of your GPU hardware.  However, all the images must be
        // the same size.  To avoid this requirement on images being the same size we
        // process them individually in this example.
        auto dets = net(img);
        win.clear_overlay();
        win.set_image(img);
        for (auto&& d : dets)
            win.add_overlay(d);

        cout << "Hit enter to process the next image." << endl;
        cin.get();
    }
}
catch(std::exception& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
}
```

the program crashes on line "auto dets = net(img);"

my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\dlib\dlib-19.4
LIBS += -LC:\dlib\dlib-19.4\mybuild\dlib_build\Release -ldlib

INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\include"
LIBS +="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64\curand.lib"
LIBS +="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64\cublas.lib"
LIBS +="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64\cublas_device.lib"
LIBS +="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64\cudnn.lib"
LIBS +="C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64\cudart_static.lib"
```

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: windows operating system??

Comment: Yes. Windows 10 x64

Comment: This is the same [example](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/dnn_mmod_face_detection_ex.cpp)??

Comment: Yes. I didn't changed anything.

Comment: it is written there  <<Note that on windows your compiler might put the test executable in a subfolder called Release. If that's the case then you have to go to that folder before running the test>>.

Comment: [Read this](https://github.com/davisking/dlib/blob/master/examples/CMakeLists.txt)

Comment: Thanks for the help man! I tried to execute the program in the release folder. Same crash. I will read the link you sent me and will be back with some answer.

Comment: Found the solution. Check the answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to define DLIB_USE_CUDA on my project and it works ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LIBS += L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\lib\x64"

LIBS += -lcurand -lcublas -lcublas_device -lcudnn -lcudart_static
```